# JQuery hoverintent: convert "on hover" to "on click"

Tags: jquery, css, html, hoverintent

1. I'm using the [Hoverintent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) JQuery plugin to make a DIV expand.
2. Now I want it to work "**on click**" rather than "**on hover**"

How do I do this? I know this is simple simple JQuery, but my knowledge is lacking. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Expand Div
    $("#expandbutton").click({
        over: ExpandDiv, 
        timeout: 100, 
        out: DoNothing
    });
}); 


function ExpandDiv(){  
    $("#expander").animate({"height":200},400, "easeOutSine");
    $("#expandbutton").css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "hidden"}).animate({opacity: 0.0});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply execute that `ExpandDiv` method on click, you can use jQuery's `.click()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Expand Div
    $("#expandbutton").click(ExpandDiv);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function directly after passing your parameters to the `click()`

```
 $("#expandbutton").click({timeout: 100, out: DoNothing},
              ExpandDiv);
```

Comment: Thanks Vash
Sorry Dave beat you to it :)